Create Gantt Chart style timeline from data in three columns
I am trying to create a timeline based on a table per the image.
I want the output to look like the right hand diagram but in 5 minute increments to reduce the size of the list as this will run 6am-6am.
It will be about 10k rows of data so this is a snapshot.
It will all be on the same worksheet.
The table
The columns will always be in the same place.
The time is "HH:MM" format.
The person name will always be unique.
The output
The header row will always be the same.
The times should be in increments of 5 minutes so if the time falls between the row time and the time above it then add which player it is.
The player should be highlighted in yellow with the cell above being blue.
I use formulas to get the information in the diagram but with it being so data hungry I suspect it will either crash Excel or take three weeks to run.
Is there a VBA equivalent to:
=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(G$1&$F2,$C:$C&$A:$A,0)),"")



I don't have time to give a full answer right now but some quick concepts: 1) If your real data is sparse, VBA likely provides a huge performance boost. Clear the gantt table then loop through the flat table. 2) If formulas, I would avoid sitting concatenation if you're worried about performance. You can do multi-condition lookups without it. 3) Powerquery is a middle-ground alternative as it allows a database-like query that is happy to execute once and wait for you to refresh it. Like formulas, it is better the less sparse your data is.


The output table is divided into 5-minute intervals. Overlaps may occur if two goals are adjacent to each other.
Overlaps players are highlighted with red.

Microsoft documentation:

Range.NumberFormatLocal property (Excel)


Range.Clear method (Excel)


Interior.Color property (Excel)


Range.Offset property (Excel)

Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, iCol As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range, olRng As Range
    Dim arrRes, iR As Long, iM As Long, iH As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long, iOffSet As Long
    ' Init. output table
    Columns("F:F").ClearContents
    Columns("F:F").NumberFormatLocal = "hh:mm"
    Range("F3").Value = "6:00"
    Range("F4:F291").Formula = "=R[-1]C+TIMEVALUE(""0:5:0"")"
    ' load header location into Dict
    Const HEADER_START = "G2"
    Dim objDic As Object, c As Range
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    With Range(HEADER_START, Range(HEADER_START).End(xlToRight))
        .Offset(1).Resize(290).Clear
        For Each c In Range(HEADER_START, Range(HEADER_START).End(xlToRight)).Cells
            objDic(c.Value) = c.Column - Range(HEADER_START).Column
        Next
    End With
    ' load data into an array
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        iH = VBA.Hour(arrData(i, 1))
        iM = VBA.Minute(arrData(i, 1))
        ' round to x5/x0 min.
        If iM Mod 5 <> 0 Then
            iM = iM + (5 - iM Mod 5)
            If iM = 60 Then
                iH = iH + 1
                iM = 0
            End If
        End If
        ' before 6am in the next day
        If iH < 6 Then iH = iH + 24
        iOffSet = ((iH - 6) * 60 + iM) / 5
        If objDic.exists(arrData(i, 3)) Then
            iCol = objDic(arrData(i, 3))
            ' populate output table
            With Range(HEADER_START).Offset(1, iCol)
                CheckOverlap olRng, .Offset(iOffSet)
                .Offset(iOffSet).Value = arrData(i, 2)
                .Offset(iOffSet).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                .Offset(iOffSet - 1).Interior.Color = vbCyan
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox "Missing team in output header: " & arrData(i, 3)
        End If
    Next i
    If Not olRng Is Nothing Then
        olRng.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
End Sub

Sub CheckOverlap(ByRef allRng As Range, cRng As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In cRng.Offset(-1).Resize(3)
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            If allRng Is Nothing Then
                Set allRng = Application.Union(c, cRng)
            Else
                Set allRng = Application.Union(allRng, c, cRng)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub





I am amazed at how quick you have managed to produce something so brilliant!! For the overlaps is there a way of flagging those? a different colour for the cell maybe? if not then thats fine. You have given me far more than i would have imagined possible! Thanks Again Taller!

I've updated the code.

Hi Taller, that is excellent. I have ran the code and it works perfectly. I have also managed to add in a loop that runs the code across a number of worksheets but cannot get the checkoverlap to follow suit. Is there a way to run on whatever worksheet the loop is up to. I've just done a "for ws 10 to sheets count" at the start and "next ws" at the end. but like i said the check bit only runs on the first ws. Sorry this has adapted from the original request where i wanted it just to run in 1 worksheet. If i'm asking too much then just don't worry about it.

What should I do when someone answers my question?
What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?
Let me know the link of new question.

Hi Taller here is the link to the new question. Thanks for providing the correct procotol for follow up questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78662126/loop-vba-through-worksheets-to-check-for-issues
